# Making ~/.bashrc function callable to set up an environment

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have an installed app lets call it `my_app` that I wish to be able to call from the command line. It is located in `/Applications/my_app.app/Contents/Resources`.

So what I was hoping to do was to have my `~/.bashrc` look like the following:

```
# .bashrc

my_app-start(){
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/my_app.app/Contents/Resources/
}
```

and then every time I want to be able to use the app from a new terminal session I would load call `my_app-start` after which I expect my app to be callable by simply typing `my_app` anywhere on my system. However my terminal does not recognise the `my_app-start` function... On another linux platform this works for me but perhaps Macs need some fiddling with ~/.bash_profile. I never understood the difference.

1. How do I make the function automatically callable?
2. Is this method a safe, sensible way of loading my application?

Answer (score 3):

Your function doesn't work because OS X starts your shell as a login shell, thus .bashrc isn't read. I wouldn't use a function in this case.
If there is only one executable file in `/Applications/my_app.app/Contents/Resources/` then I would use an alias.

I would use separate files when changing your environment. Set your PATH and whatever in these/this file(s) then at any time source your environment file and your good to go. As an example, I have the AST tool set installed. I'm testing the tools supplied by AST but need to use the minimum PATH supplied by OS X and the PATH to the AST tools. So, I have to modify my PATH that is set in my .profile. I've created a file .astenv in my home folder.

```
#
#  .astenv
#
#  The AT&T Software Technology tools from AT&T Research
#
#

PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)
ASTPATH=$HOME/local/opt/ast-master/arch/darwin/bin

PATH=$ASTPATH:$PATH
export PATH
```

To use this config file,  I can start a new terminal session and source the file,

```
. ~/.astenv
```

or in my current terminal session start a new instance of my shell then source the file.

```
ksh
. ~/.astenv
```

When I `exit` this shell, I'm back to my original environment.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification about login shell. Im not exactly sure about your second point could you please elaborate (I'm not a very experienced linux user)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a symlink in `/usr/local/bin`?

```
ln -s /foo/bar/hello_world.app /usr/local/bin/hello_world.app
```

You won't have to create any functions in `.bashrc`

In fact, what I have done with scripts that I have written that have multiple versions, is create a symlink to a file with the text "-latest" and then copy the latest version into that file.

My symlink looks like this:

```
ln -s /foo/bar/my_app-latest.app /usr/local/bin/my_app.app
```

Whenever I have a new version, I just copy to `my_app-latest.app` and everything is updated.

Comment: Interesting - is the symlink peramanent or do I have to call it everytime I open a new terminal? The reason I wanted to do it via a function is so that I could choose to set up the environment or not when I open a new terminal.

Comment: I also read that ideally you would link to `/usr/local/sbin` and not `/usr/sbin` though I'm not sure why.

Comment: The symlink is permanent.  Every time you open terminal, it will be available since it's in your path.  It may be `/usr/local/sbin`...between FreeBSD, OS X, Linux, and Windows, it tough to keep them all straight.

Comment: `/usr/sbin` is not user-writeable on El Capitan, I've changed it to `/usr/local/bin` in your answer.

Comment: @patrix Appreciate that...I was on my Surface Pro 3 yesterday and couldn't test out